EF Core 8 SearchCriteria Filter in ThenInclude Filter
public class PersonByAddressCityOrZip : Specification<Person>
{
     private string _city { get; set; }
     public int _zip { get; set; }
     public string _street { get; set; }

     public PersonByAddressCityOrZip(string city, int zip,string street)
     {
         _city = city;
         _zip = zip;
         _street = street;

         var citySpec = _city != string.Empty ? new AddressByCitySpecification(_city) : null;
         var streetSpec = _street != string.Empty ? new AddressByStreetSpecification(_street) : null;
         var zipSpec = _zip > 0 ? new AddressByZipSpecification(_zip) : null;

         Specification<Address> combinedSpec = null;

         if (citySpec != null)
         {
             combinedSpec = citySpec;
         }

         if (streetSpec != null)
         {
             combinedSpec = combinedSpec == null ? streetSpec : combinedSpec.Or(streetSpec);
         }

         if (zipSpec != null)
         {
             combinedSpec = combinedSpec == null ? zipSpec : combinedSpec.Or(zipSpec);
         }

         if (combinedSpec != null)
         {
             AddInclude(p => p.AddressList.Where(combinedSpec.ToExpression().Compile()));
         }
         else
             AddInclude(p => p.AddressList);
     }

     public bool IsSatisfied(Person item)
     {
         return true;
     }

     public override Expression<Func<Person, bool>> ToExpression()
     {
         return person =>  person.AddressList.Any(a => a.City.Contains(_city) || a.Zip == _zip);
     }
}

This solution does not work, this line    " AddInclude(p => p.AddressList.Where(combinedSpec.ToExpression().Compile()));" get an error:

System.ArgumentException : Expression of type
'System.Func2[EFCore_Swagger.Models.Address,System.Boolean]' cannot be used for parameter of type  'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression1[System.Func2[EFCore_Swagger.Models.Address,System.Boolean]]'  of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable1[EFCore_Swagger.Models.Address]
Where[Address](System.Linq.IQueryable1[EFCore_Swagger.Models.Address], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression1[System.Func`2[EFCore_Swagger.Models.Address,System.Boolean]])' (Parameter 'arg1')

I'm looking for an elegant solution to set the search critiera street, zip, city dynamically in the ThenInclude Where condition

.Compile() cannot be used here. And there is no "elegant" solution. Expression Tree should be built dynamically. For example by LINQKit and it's Extension method Invoke.

I would suggest to use LINQKit. It needs configuring DbContextOptions:
builder
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
    .WithExpressionExpanding(); // enabling LINQKit extension

Then you can express your include in the following way:
AddInclude(p => p.AddressList.Where(combinedSpec.ToExpression().Expand()));

Or via Invoke
AddInclude(p => p.AddressList.Where(x => combinedSpec.ToExpression().Invoke(x)));


thx @Svyatoslav Danyliv but it has no effect.

Added another one. I really don't know what is under hood of your ToExpression, but it should return LambdaExpression with one parameter of type Address.

In the second sample above is an example with the same behavior as in the first case

Which behaviour? Probably you have built wrong ExpressionTree.

The where clause does not accept an expression,  with expression Invoke its working. Thx

For testing i created a new LinqKit project:
base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
 optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(@"Data Source=LinkKitDB.db;")
                 .WithExpressionExpanding(); 


Expression<Func<Book, bool>> criteria1 = b => b.NoOfPages > 1000;
Expression<Func<Book, bool>> criteria2 = b => b.Title.Contains("Introduction") || criteria1.Invoke(b);

var result = dbContext.Books.Any(criteria1.Expand());
In the Books where clauses it works like expected.
var authorsWithBooks = dbContext.Authors.Include(a => a.Books.Any(criteria1.Expand()));

In the Include, Any does not have a method signatur for the expression.

List' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and the best
extension method overload 'Queryable.Any(IQueryable,
Expression<Func<Book, bool>>)'  requires a receiver of type
'System.Linq.IQueryable<LinqKit.Book>'

Ok, then instead of i use Func, in the runtime i receive the follow error Messages.

Expression of type 'System.Func2[LinqKit.Book,System.Boolean]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression1[System.Func2[LinqKit.Book,System.Boolean]]' of method 'Boolean Any[Book](System.Linq.IQueryable1[LinqKit.Book],
System.Linq.Expressions.Expression1[System.Func2[LinqKit.Book,System.Boolean]])'
(Parameter 'arg1')

I am out of ideas to use includes clauses to with the expression

Expression in Include should haver return IEnumerable<Entity>. But Any is bool.
